# Adding customized SOAP Header in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to get the desired customized header for my SOAP request:

What I need:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <urn:SessionHeader>
        <urn:sessionId>abcdef1234</urn:sessionId>
    </urn:SessionHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <urn:sessionId xmlns:urn="www.dummy.com">
        abcdef1234
    </urn:sessionId>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I need to remove the `xmlns` from the childnode!

Below is the Java code I'm using:

```
SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
SOAPHeaderElement messageId =  soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName("www.dummy.com", "sessionId","urn"));
messageId.setTextContent("urn:abcdef1234");
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the namespace declaration but still use a namespace? - Use a namespace-capable parser at the receiving end.

Comment: Hi! @JimmyB, the receiving end is not in my control... :(
Isn't there any other way I can make it possible??

Comment: Sorry, I do not know that. However, I do know that using a namespace without declaring it produces invalid XML. - Maybe worth a try: `addHeaderElement( `[`soapEnvelope.createName("urn:sessionId")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPEnvelope.html#createName%28java.lang.String%29) `)`.

Comment: @JimmyB,
I've managed to get a solution: See below:

_Here **serverM2M** is the link of the namespace_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I managed to get a solution and it is working fine! @JimmyB

```
    //SOAP Header
    SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
    SOAPHeaderElement sessionHeader =  soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(new QName(serverM2M, "SessionHeader","urn"));
    SOAPElement sessionID = sessionHeader.addChildElement(new QName(serverM2M, "sessionId","urn"));
    sessionID.addTextNode(termTwo);
```

Which gives me an output:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
  <urn:SessionHeader>
     <urn:sessionId>00D560000004Zxv!AQMAQGTYYqKa0NwwPNSY7QLnfn1aeyjsloOJQAvU4K53pJlPrGiI0rkdCfcEmN7va2c5caH3XmG.OvTxeU3hPAKwdlWxIlf8</urn:sessionId>
  </urn:SessionHeader>
```